# Passing Enumerations in a Function that's in a Struct (in C)

Tags: c, function, enums, struct, argument-passing

I have looked up how to pass an enumeration in a function, but that method doesn't work when both the function and enumeration are declared in a structure. Here is my code :

test_setup.h:

```
     1 #ifndef TEST_SETUP_H_
     2 #define TEST_SETUP_H_
     3 #include <stdio.h>
     4 #include <stdlib.h>
     5 
     6 
     7 typedef struct _test_setup {
     8 
     9   int *partner;            
    10   int *send_first;         
    11   double *results;         
    12 
    13   enum { CHIP_WIDE, NODE_WIDE, SYSTEM_WIDE } SomeMatches;
    14   void match_partners(SomeMatches match);
    15 
    16 } test_setup;              
    17 
    18 #endif
```

test_setup.c :

```
     1 #include "../includes/test_setup.h"
     2 
     3 void match_partners(SomeMatches match) { 
     4   if (match == CHIP_WIDE) {
     5 
     6   }
     7   else if (match == NODE_WIDE) {
     8 
     9   }
    10   else if (match == SYSTEM_WIDE) {
    11 
    12   }
    13   else {
    14 
    15   }
    16 }`
```

Error:

```
    In file included from src/test_setup.c:1:
    src/../includes/test_setup.h:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘match’
    src/../includes/test_setup.h:16: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
    src/test_setup.c:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘match’
    make: *** [setup.o] Error 1
```

I have tried every combination of declaring an enumeration and using it in the function parameters, but nothing has worked. Any ideas would be much appreciated. I am compiling with mpicc (because the rest of the program uses MPI functions) but I have tried with GNU GCC and I get the same warnings/errors.

Comment: I don't believe you can create an enum inside of a structure as far as I know. I could be wrong but in all my years of programming in C I've never seen it done that way.

Comment: Hmmm, okay thanks Ramos. I'll see if anyone else comes up with anything. It's not the end of the world if the enum isn't inside the struct, but it would be nice ;)

Comment: Is this supposed to be `C` or `C++` ? In your question you mention `test_setup.cpp` but the error message says `test_setup.c` and the question is tagged as `c`. (You can only put enums and functions inside a struct in `C++`.)

Comment: @Paul : Oops! My mistake Paul! I'm a natural c++ programmer, so thats my default, but this is infact in C - fixed

Comment: I guess I was right since I believed this was C since the tag in the question was for C but you meant C++, I'll see if I can correct that for you.

Comment: @Alex: You can't define member functions that way either in C.  Why not just use C++? ;)

Comment: @Merlyn : Well, I would love to do C++, but my mentors would rather we use C :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For C**

If you truly want C, then you simply can't do any of this.

- You can't define a member function in a struct
- You can't define a named enumeration nested in a struct

**For C++**

Use the scope-resolution operator `::`

```
#include<iostream>

struct Test
{
  enum SomeEnum { TEST1, TEST2, TEST3 };
  void SomeFunction(SomeEnum e);
};

void Test::SomeFunction(Test::SomeEnum e)
{
  std::cout << e << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Test t;
  t.SomeFunction(Test::TEST1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need the function and the enumeration in the same struct, but I will try that

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just scrap the struct then and do it a different way. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in C, here are the workarounds:

```
// define the enumeration at file scope:

typedef enum {CHIP_WIDE, NODE_WIDE, SYSTEM_WIDE} SomeMatches;

// declare a *pointer* to a function in the struct:
typedef struct { 
    int *partner;
    int *send_first;
    double *results;

    void (*match_partners)(SomeMatches match);   
} test_setup;
```

Define your function as normal:

```
void match_partners(SomeMatches match)
{
  if (match == CHIP_WIDE) {}
  else if (match == NODE_WIDE) {}
  else if (match == SYSTEM_WIDE) {}
}
```

Then when you create an instance of the struct, assign the function pointer:

```
test_setup t;
t.match_partners = match_partners;
```

You don't need to explicitly dereference the function pointer to call it, so you can execute your function as

```
t.match_partners(CHIP_WIDE);
```

although if you *want* to dereference it explicitly, use

```
(*t.match_partners)(CHIP_WIDE);
```

Note that C doesn't have any equivalent to the `this` pointer; if `match_partners` depends on information contained in the struct instance, you'll have to explicitly pass that instance as a separate argument:

```
void match_parthers(SomeMatches matches, test_setup *instance) 
{
}
...
typedef struct {
  ...
  void (*match_partners)(SomeMatches matches, test_setup *instance);
  ...
} test_setup;
...
test_setup t;
t.match_partners = match_partners;
t.match_partners(CHIP_WIDE, &t);
```

Note that for the struct definition to be legal, we have to pass the instance as a *pointer*, since the `test_setup` type isn't complete at that point.

**EDIT**

That last sentence isn't terribly clear; let me try again.  A struct definition cannot refer to an instance of itself, because the struct type isn't *complete* until the closing `}`.  IOW, the following is not legal:

```
struct foo
{
  ...
  struct foo bar;
  ...
};
```

However, a struct can refer to a *pointer* to another instance of the same type, so the following is legal:

```
struct foo
{
  ...
  struct foo *bar;
  ...
};
```

The same logic applies to the function pointer declaration; the `instance` parameter needs to be declared as `test_setup *`, since the `test_setup` type definition isn't complete at that point.  As Merlyn points out in the comments, you probably want the instance to be mutable anyway, but the language requires you to use a pointer in that circumstance.

Comment: +1;  Also a comment to your last sentence.  In something that you'd define like a method, you'd want the `instance` that you pass to be a pointer, anyway.  If it is a mutator function, and you don't pass `instance` as a pointer, then you are not going to see any changes to your structure's state.

Comment: @Merlyn: True.  My basic point was that for the function declaration in the struct to be legal, you'd have to use a pointer to `test_setup`, otherwise you'd get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Your enum does not have a proper name (it doesn't have a tag) and cannot be referenced from distinct points in the code. Try this:

```
enum SomeMatches { CHIP_WIDE, NODE_WIDE, SYSTEM_WIDE };
struct _test_setup {
     /* ... */
     enum SomeMatches SomeMatches;
     void (*match_partners)(enum SomeMatches match);
     /* ... */
};
```

Sprinkle `typedefs` at will, or leave things bare ...

Answer (score -1):

First of all `#define TEST_SETUP_H_` goes *before* `#ifndef TEST_SETUP_H_`. Otherwise your code will be completely commented out to the compiler.

You don't name a typedef struct like that it goes as such:
        typedef struct struct_name{
               /*contents*/
        };

`void match_partners(SomeMatches match)` can be `void match_partners(void)` and use the variable inside the function because with that header file you've made it global and don't need to pass it.

Comment: -1: so little lines, so many erroneous info: the `#ifndef / #define` method is ok; the usage is `typedef *thing* *new name*;`; there's no variable defined in the header file